# Calculate speed using javascript

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I am trying to calculate the download speed of an image, but the speed comes out as infinity. What am I doing wrong?

```
var imageAddr = "/images/image.jpg" + "?n=" + Math.random();
var startTime, endTime;
var downloadSize = 200000;
var download = new Image();
download.onload = function () {
    endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    showResults();
}
startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
download.src = imageAddr;

function showResults() {
    var duration = Math.round((endTime - startTime) / 1000);
    var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
    var speedBps = Math.round(bitsLoaded / duration);
    var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
    alert("Your connection speed is: \n" + 
           speedBps + " bps\n"   + 
           speedKbps + " kbps\n" + 
           speedMbps + " Mbps\n" );
}
```

Comment: This is pure JavaScript, removed the non relevant tags.

Comment: For those that have successfully used this Javascript code, did you initially encounter no calls going to "download.onload"?  This is exactly what I am experiencing and I am still trying to find out why.

Comment: thre's the cache problem

Answer (score 9):

Just don't round the duration.

```
 var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
```

Comment: I got the download speed as 13793103 bps,13469.83 kbps13.15 Mbps.This is incorrect as my internet connection is limited to 3Mbps.This should be 1.3 Mbps

Comment: First, you have to make sure that the image isn't sent gzipped, because that would make it a bit faster (not much, but inaccurate). Then, you need to make sure that you are having the right `downloadSize` number. Finally, make sure that the image file is not on `localhost`.

Comment: What  is it that about the download size?

Comment: The size, in bytes, of the image that you used. More size it is, more waiting time, and more accuracy.

Comment: @Rajeev sounds like you're performing the test on the local server itself so you're measuring the network or hard disk speed. Host this code on some remote server then you'll get real results.

Comment: @Thai:Can we deduce upload/download result from this.

Comment: You can, but that's not very accurate. You can instead use Speedtest.net or it's widgets because they have servers dedicated for speed testing.

Comment: Is this an accurate computation of the network speed?

Answer (score 8):

`duration` is probably coming out 0, and a positive number divided by zero yields the special value of positive infinity in JavaScript.

Comment: Thats what i guessed ,but final values speedBps ,     speedKbps,     speedMbps all are  are infinity and these are not divided by duration

Comment: `speedBps` is computed like this: `var speedBps = Math.round(bitsLoaded / duration);`.  If `duration` is 0, then `speedBps` will be infinity.  And since the other two speed variables are calculated from `speedBps`, they will also be infinity.

Answer (score 8):

Just think about it: `endTime` and `startTime` are in `[ms]`, so their difference is also in ms.

Example with an image loading for *300 ms*:

```
Math.round((endTime - startTime) / 1000);
-> Math.round(300 / 1000);
-> Math.round(0.3);
-> 0
```

Leave `Math.round` out of the snippet.

And then as the others stated `duration = 0` will lead to

```
speedBps = bitsLoaded / duration
-> speedBps = bitsLoaded / 0
-> speedBps = Infinity
```

**But**, please note that you can't get accurate results like this. There is latency, connection time, time to first byte, etc which [cannot be measured](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/110103_NS_7BH5/1/details/) by your example, and for an image < *1 MB* they will lead to very inaccurate results.

Comment: How to determine the upload/download limit from this

Comment: I had tested this method and several similar techniques with very little luck in getting meaningful results from the numbers. In my testing small medium and large files yielded wildly different rates of download. One would expect the similar rates - so I think rates is not an accurate measurement on which to reach a conclusion about speed.....

Answer (score 3):

because your duration is close to 0, 
then you should try

> var duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000;