# How to get Content-Length at the end of request?

Tags: php

[headers_sent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) will tell me when output was sent to the browser. However, it can be that no body was sent, e.g. 302 redirect.

How do I tell in [register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) context what content has been sent to the browser, or at least what was `Content-Length`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but maybe you could `ob_start()` at the start of your file and then use `ob_get_length()` to get the Content-Length and finally echo with `ob_end_flush()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content lenght header will no being set by apache if it is a PHP script. This is because the webserver can't know about this as the content is dynamically created. However the headers have to sent **before** the body. So the only way to get the length of the content is to generate it, obtain it's length, send the header and then send the content.

In PHP you can use [`ob_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) set of functions (output buffering) to achieve this. Like this:

```
ob_start();

echo 'hello world'; // all your application's code comes here

register_shutdown_function(function() {
    header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());
    ob_end_flush();
});
```

**Warning** This will be unreliable if you are using `gzip` encoded transfer. There has been posted [a workaround on the PHP web site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php#59294),

Also you might need to know that output buffers can be nested in PHP. If there is another `ob_start()` call in my example above than you'll end up seeing nothing in the browser because just the inner buffer gets flushed (into the outer one)

The following example takes care on this. In order to ease the process it just overwrites the header multiple times, which shouldn't be a performance issue as `header()` is basically a simple string operation. PHP *sends* the headers only before some output or at the end of the script.

Here comes the code which has been tested gzip safe and works reliable with nested unclosed buffers:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

echo 'hello world';

// another ob_start call. The programmer missed to close it.
ob_start();

register_shutdown_function(function() {
    // loop through buffers and flush them. After the operation the
    // Content-Lenght header will contain the total of them all
    while(ob_get_level()) {
        header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length(), TRUE);
        ob_end_flush();
    }
});
```

Comment: I just wrote this in a comment!  Great minds think alike! :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hehe :)... I think this fact is a big problem with HTTP. Otherwise you could easily write a file system driver for HTTP, mount it, and replace google by grep -r. (back to the roots :)

Comment: That's not an option. Please note that question is asking to get `Content-Length` in the `register_shutdown_context`. Putting everything into buffer, does not necessarily mean there was output sent to the browser.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas `ob_flush()` ensures that this will being send to the browser. Of course you will have to put it to the end of the script, or use a more elaborated framework for this. (can be self written)

Comment: Your suggestion will break with https://gist.github.com/gajus/3b85233c18e82e495bac. Instead replace your code example with: https://gist.github.com/gajus/e062007dfef4d17f4d96. So far this seems the only viable solution.

Comment: "you'll end up seeing nothing in the browser because just the inner buffer gets flushed (into the outer one)." That's not correct. Output buffer will be unfold automatically. You do not need to call `ob_end_flush` at all in your script.

Comment: No, I'm using it for the the calculation of the `content-length`. After the last loop, content-length contains the size of the outer buffer.