# How to know how much of a file is downloaded from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big data file of size 8 MB. Now while my page is downloading it from the server, I would like to present a status update on how much is downloaded, e.g. 56% is downloaded. The data file in itself is a .js file!

I would like to do it from my javascript. I was thinking of the below option.

1) First measure network speed.
2) Then do a linear interpolation as I know the size of the file.

But measuring netspeed in JS is not very reliable given connection timing, caching, rendering etc etc.

Is there any direct approach, where I can straightway get the size of the partially downloaded file and calculate how much is downloaded so far.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could load if after page load with an httprequest and use the onreadystatechange event to show percentage complete

Comment: could you please elaborate, possible with an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399641/ajax-page-download-progress

Comment: @user3001408 this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279534/how-to-know-external-js-is-loaded-or-not-and-put-percentage-loader-until-that-ti

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmlhttprequest progress event to find out file upload progress in a HTML5 compatible browser.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
 }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: op asked for download, not upload ;)

Comment: I am downloading the file, not uploading

Comment: Oops :-), but  according to link you can use this event for download as well.  But I am not sure for eg: how a browser can know file size in advance.